# How to flatten pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my pandas dataframe, and I would like to flatten. How can I do that ?

**The input I have**

```
key column
1 {'health_1': 45, 'health_2': 60, 'health_3': 34, 'health_4': 60, 'name': 'Tom'}   
2 {'health_1': 28, 'health_2': 10, 'health_3': 42, 'health_4': 07, 'name': 'John'}  
3 {'health_1': 86, 'health_2': 65, 'health_3': 14, 'health_4': 52, 'name': 'Adam'}
```

**The expected output**

All the `health` and `name` will become a `column name` of their own with their corresponding `values`. In no particular order.

```
health_1 health_2 health_3 health_4 name key
45          60       34       60    Tom  1
28          10       42       07    John 2
86          65       14       52    Adam 3
```

Comment: Please show the expected output. Do you want e.g. 4 rows (health_...) from each source row?

Comment: @Valdi_Bo not sure if I understood you correctly, basically every row has 5 columns. If that helps you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with **one line** solution,

```
df_expected = pd.concat([df, df['column'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1).drop('column', axis = 1)
```

**Full version**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"column":[
{'health_1': 45, 'health_2': 60, 'health_3': 34, 'health_4': 60, 'name': 'Tom'}   ,
{'health_1': 28, 'health_2': 10, 'health_3': 42, 'health_4': 7, 'name': 'John'}  ,
{'health_1': 86, 'health_2': 65, 'health_3': 14, 'health_4': 52, 'name': 'Adam'}
]})

df_expected = pd.concat([df, df['column'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1).drop('column', axis = 1)
print(df_expected)
```

**DEMO:** https://repl.it/repls/ButteryFrightenedFtpclient

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
df['column'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Gives:

```
   health_1  health_2  health_3  health_4  name
0  45        60        34        60        Tom 
1  28        10        42        7         John
2  86        65        14        52        Adam
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i, index=[0]) for i in df.column], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   health_1  health_2  health_3  health_4  name
0        45        60        34        60   Tom
1        28        10        42         7  John
2        86        65        14        52  Adam
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions using `apply` are going overboard.  You can create your desired `DataFrame` using a list of dictionaries like you have in your `column` Series.  You can easily *get* this list of dictionaries by using the [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) method:

```
res = pd.concat([df.key, pd.DataFrame(df.column.tolist())], axis=1)
print(res)
```

```
   key  health_1  health_2  health_3  health_4  name
0    1        45        60        34        60   Tom
1    2        28        10        42         7  John
2    3        86        65        14        52  Adam
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand - This is the default format for a DataFrame?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
{'health_1': 45, 'health_2': 60, 'health_3': 34, 'health_4': 60, 'name': 'Tom'}   ,
{'health_1': 28, 'health_2': 10, 'health_3': 42, 'health_4': 7, 'name': 'John'}  ,
{'health_1': 86, 'health_2': 65, 'health_3': 14, 'health_4': 52, 'name': 'Adam'}
])
```

Comment: your answer is how I wanted to look like, but unfortunately, I have the columns nested in the row with their values. This is data I get from a really bad server, that I need to convert to a pandas dataframe

Comment: the one I am presenting above is what I have. A dataframe with 2 columns, key and column. I would like to unpack the rows, so that each key in the row becomes a column in itself